# PHP - how can I echo <script> tag with an src attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, echo, src, script-tag

I've looked around but couldn't find an answer to this.

How can I echo a script tag that has an src attribute?
When I try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">document.writeln(3); 
</script>';
```

the code fails.

But when I do this and remove the src tag:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.writeln(3);</script>'
```

the code works.

what am I overlooking and how can I make the first version work?

Answer (score 4):

You either include a `src` attribute, which references a file for the code or include the code directly in the `script` tag. You don't put both.

Answer (score 1):

It should actually be like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.writeln(3);</script>';
```